# URL whitelist without proxy behind Squid?

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy, squid, education

Long story short, I'm searching for a tool or config that blocks all network traffic except whitelisted ones and works without a own proxy.

In my institution every device that wants to connect to the internet requires proxy configuration. Therefore we have a central squid server running.

Now I wanted to create a save exam environment, where network functions are  limited to 1-2 whitelisted domains. Since the used PCs vary or students can bring the own device, I can't hardcode the IP adresses in the central squid. So I'd like to realize this with a custom Ubuntu live usb drive.

The first idea that came to my mind was a filter tool like DansGuardian. However, these tools I found all require their own local squid to work. But as you remember, there's already one in use that can't be bypassed.

Comment: Is modifying `/etc/hosts` an option ? Do the exam takers have root access ?

Comment: They won't know the root password. The hosts file may be an option if you be able to allow an entire domain, not just a single server IP. Does that work?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not the best way then. You could block a range of ips if you know netmask, something like here https://www.webmasterworld.com/linux/3175193.htm  Maybe there's better solutions. Just wait for other answers or comments